# SQL in C# - why so verbose?

Tags: c#, sql

I used postgreSQL in PHP, and this was simple : when you make a query, you do :

```
$result = pg_query($conn, "SELECT author, email FROM authors WHERE dest='" + pg_escape_string($s) + "'");
```

Simple. Secure (as far as I know).

Now I want to do the same thing with SQLite in C# :

```
SQLiteCommand query = m_conn.CreateCommand();
query.CommandText = "SELECT author, email FROM authors WHERE dest=@param";
query.Parameters.Add("@dest", SqlDbType.String).Value = s;
m_datareader = query.ExecuteReader();
```

Is it not a bit of an overkill ? If not, why ?

From what I know, in the end, the string sent to the database is still a string, why should it go trough this instead of just manually sanitizing unsafe strings ? If in ASP .NET to print some unsafe text to HTML is it also

```
htmlAdd.Text("<div>@param1</div>");
htmlAdd.Parameters.Add("@param1").Value = unsafeUsername;
```

?

I wanted to do this class :

```
class QueryResultSet
{
    public QueryResultSet(SQLiteConnection conn, string queryText)
    {
        m_conn = conn;
        m_conn.Open();
        SQLiteCommand query = m_conn.CreateCommand();
        query.CommandText = queryText;
        m_datareader = query.ExecuteReader();
    }
    public object this[string key]
    {
        get { return m_datareader[key]; }
    }
    public bool Read()
    {
        return m_datareader.Read();
    }
    ~QueryResultSet()
    {
        m_conn.Close();
    }
    private SQLiteConnection m_conn;
    private SQLiteDataReader m_datareader;
}
```

But now I have to change the method in :

```
public QueryResultSet(SQLiteConnection conn, string queryText, Dictionary<string,string> params)
```

That will cause the code before the method and into it to double its size.

Any standard way to do it ? If this class isn't a good idea, how to avoid having to do 10 lines for each request ?

Comment: Aside from anything else, you should *not* be closing database connections in a C# finalizer. You should open the connection, read the data, and close it directly. Either that, or implement IDisposable and get your clients to dispose you.

Comment: The idea is that I read the data in the block where I initialize the QueryResultSet, so it is closed immediately (except if there are some subtleties in garbage collection I didn't understood).

Comment: I suspect there are - you seem to be expecting the finalizer to be called as soon as you leave the block. That won't happen. Finalization is non-deterministic in C# and .NET in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use an extension method

```
public static IDataReader GetReader(this IDbConnection conn,string query, params object[] values) {
  var Command=conn.CreateCommand();
  var paramNames=Enumerable.Range(1,values.Length).Select(i=>string.Format("@param{0}",i)).ToArray();
  Command.CommandText=string.Format(query,paramNames);
  for (var i=0;i<values.Length;i++) {
    var param=Command.CreateParameter();
    param.ParameterName=paramNames[i];
    param.Value=values[i];
    Command.Parameters.Add(param);
  }
  return Command.ExecuteReader();
}
```

Then you can just in your code use the string format syntax for your query.

e.g.

```
Conn.GetReader("SELECT author, email FROM authors WHERE dest={0}",dest);
```

Comment: Seems like an interesting solution, I'll look into it.

Comment: If you are using resharper don't forget to mark the method with the StringFormatAttribute so it can warn you about mismatched variables - http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Code_Analysis__String_Formatting_Methods.html

Answer (score 8):

Parameterised queries are the better choice as they're normally type safe, handle any escaping, literal formatting, etc for you, as well as allowing the server/backend to cache the compiled query for better performance.

Most database engines will allow you to do both "plain old sql" and parameterised queries.

Of course, building up full SQL strings requires you to know the exact formats and data types used by the RDBMS as they all differ.

Comment: The question is : I'm using an SQLite connection in my code, so anyway it won't work on mySQL or any other SQL variant. Here, instead of being able to do sqlite_sanitize(s), I call an huge method who will do exactly the same thing. And by the way, how can the database cache a request which was unknown from it two functions calls ago ? wouldn't it be more logical to cache all the parametrized queries at the program's initialization ? I'm beginning to understand the idea, but there are still points I don't find logical.

Comment: By using parameterized queries the command text you send to the database will be identical (as the parameters are parsed seperately), this allows the Database engine to maintain a cache of the query plan based on the command text - improving perfomance.

Comment: @Clement: for it to work, you could use an SQLLite provider for ADO.NET. Never tried but just googled and there seem to exist open source implementations.

Answer (score 2):

There are some very effective tools to help with this. Since you have SQL and don't need complexity, a micro-ORM such as "dapper" is a reasonable choice:

```
var result=conn.Query<Author>("SELECT author, email FROM authors WHERE dest=@s",
    new {s});
```

or if you want to use `dynamic` instead of strong-typing:

```
var result=conn.Query("SELECT author, email FROM authors WHERE dest=@s",new {s});
```

Not so bad now? You could then consume that via something like:

```
foreach(var obj in result) {
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", obj.Author, obj.Email");
}
```

Comment: All dapper seems to do is cut out a few lines of ADO.NET here and there. Is this worth the risk of using an unsupported third-party compoment which probably hasn't had as rigourous testing as raw ADO.NET?

Comment: @CraigJ IMO, **absolutely** (although I may be biased). That ADO.NET code (relating to adding parameters, or materializing rows) is *not your application*. Best case: it costs you time; worst case: you get silly typos due to the sheer mind-numbing tedium of it. It isn't tricky code - there's no need to write it ourselves. YMMV, of course, and if the concept doesn't make you happy, don't use it...

Answer (score 1):

Get and ORM or abstract this bolierplate code:

```
public static IDataReader ExecuteCommand(this IDbConnection dbConnection, 
    string query, object parameters)
{
    // Left as an exercise
}

var dataReader = connection.ExecuteCommand(
    "select * from Foo where Bar = @bar and Baz = @baz",
    new { bar = "12332", baz = DateTime.Now });
```

Comment: you will have to use reflection to retrieve the parameters' values, right?

Comment: A `Dictionary<string, object>` is better for the `parameters`.

Comment: That boilerplate stuff seems unnecessary and risky. The ADO.NET functions virtually provide this anyway and are far less likely to contain any bugs.

Answer (score 0):

If you look a bit into the standard ORM frameworks for C# ([Linq to SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425822.aspx), [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399572.aspx)), you could eventually come up with something like this:

```
using (DBClasses db = new DBClasses())
{
    IEnumerable<AuthorInfo> authors = from item in db.authors
                                      where item.dest == s
                                      select item;
}
```

This code extracts the authors in a strongly-typed manner, you won't have to type in your SQL queries yourself, nor you have to manage the connections / SQL readers.

Handling databases the 'old-school' way is only justified if you need high performance.

Answer (score 0):

You can just write the plain SQL if you want:

```
SQLiteCommand query = m_conn.CreateCommand();
query.CommandText = "SELECT author, email FROM authors WHERE dest='" + s + "'";
m_datareader = query.ExecuteReader();
```

I generally add this:

```
DataTable T = query.ExecuteReader().Tables[0];
```

As a DataTable is more useful to me than a DataReader.  On a sucessful query, you always get the one datatable result.

Comment: I don't think that the s without escaping will do much good (unless you are sure that there are no characters like ' or non-ASCII).

Comment: Yes, I agree that this is risky if you don't compensate for invalid values of "s".  In my code I wrap "s" in a home-grown function called "SqlString(string inputSql)"   I do with there were some built-in function to use but I do not know of any.  I agree with the author, though, that writing the paramaterized query is just a big pain in the neck.